# Umbraco 7 get media property value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor-2, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco 7 and MVC. I have added a property called 'teaser' to the media file type. When I upload a media file, the back office interface recognizes the new property and allows me to set its value. 
I am, however, unable to figure out how to access that value for use in the interface. Here's the code:

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("audioFiles")) {
var audioIdList = CurrentPage.audioFiles.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var audioList = Umbraco.TypedMedia(audioIdList);
<ul class="audioFileList"> @{
foreach (var af in audioList) {
        <li>
            <a href="@af.Url">@af.Name</a><br />
            @af.teaser;
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

}

When I run this code, it throws an error saying that "'Umbraco.Web.Models.PublishedContentBase' does not contain a definition for 'teaser'". The Url and the Name are retrieved just fine. It's only the added 'teaser' that's a problem.
Thanks - Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 @af.GetPropertyValue("teaser")
```

You can only use `af.teaser` if you are using the dynamic "CurrentPage" object.  In this case you inherit from a TypedList which gives you strongly typed .Net objects.  These do not contain your custom properties.

If you like the dynamics more, you should replace `var audioList = Umbraco.TypedMedia(audioIdList);` by `var audioList = Umbraco.Media(audioIdList);`. This will give you a dynamic object.

Comment: Thanks. The solution was to change Umbraco.TypedMedia to Umbraco.Media. Before that, neither solution worked (I actually had also tried @af.GetPropertyValue with no success.) After that, both solutions work.